# Scaling factor for atmospheric correction in GEOMATICA

Tags: atmospheric-correction, geomatica

Wondering if there's any one who's familiar with using ATCOR for atmospheric correction in GEOMATICA. What is the best scale factor? I used the default setting and then divided my image by 1000. This seems to work for one of my images, but when I tried the same value for another image from another area, spectra from corrected image is no where near my in-situ reference data.

Comment: Were you able to find a answer to this problem? I am have the exact same issue myself right now.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm using 1000 and looks fine (but will let you know when I try ATCOR again if it isn't 1000). I guess another way to determine the right scale is to compare with images corrected with other atmo. corr. algorithms...